# How to change a value of a variable upon clicking a button in InlineKeyboard - Telegram Pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I am using pyrogram!

What I want to do is -

```
call = 'SOS, help me!'

def test(client, message):
message.reply_text(text="This is a InlineKeyboardMarkup example", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([InlineKeyboardButton(
                            "Button",
                            call='No'
                        )])
```

I want that after clicking the button, the value of call variable changes from "SOS, help me!" to "No"

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [edit_message_reply_markup](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/edit_message_reply_markup#pyrogram.Client.edit_message_reply_markup) method to edit inline button values.